# Keyboard and Mouse Not working after few minutes in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: keyboard, mouse

Keyboard and Mouse Not working after few minutes in ubuntu 13.10. I think this problem is not associate with hardware, because I had changed new mouse and keyboard also but this problem still occured. In my case after few minutes volume is autometically up and down,mouse not working properly(won't click in textfield but sometimes it click in button) and keyboard num lock on but it's all key not working.
Please help me I got frustration from this problem!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

In order to analyze the problem, just open bash and type:

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

No wait untill the problem occurs again - you will hopefully see something like "USB Device disconnected" now.

Comment: I don't understand? This should only show you the reason, it doesn't fix anything...